# I have exhausted the iterator (in python not pandas)

Tags: python, loops, iterator

I have a csv file with two columns: 1. date (example Jan - 2010) and 2. Profit/Losses (its a number).
I am trying to get two results: total number of months and total amount of profits and losses.

Example:

```
  Total Months: 86
  Total: $38382578
```

I was able to run the code to get the total of months and it worked. Then I added the second part to calculate the total of the second column and the result is zero and for what I can see it is because I have exhausted the iterator. I need to go back to the beginning of my loop but I cannot find the right way to do it.
It is my first week with python and I am just exploring how to run things here. I hope I can find the answer! This is my code:

```
import os
import csv

budgetdatapath = os.path.join('../..', 'gt-atl-data-pt-03-2020-u-c', '03-Python', 'Homework', 'PyBank', 'Resources', 'budget_data.csv')


with open(budgetdatapath) as csvbudgetfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvbudgetfile, delimiter=',')
    #print(csvreader)


# Read the header row first 

csv_header = next(csvbudgetfile)

#Method 1:  total number of months - count lines in the file
lines=len(list(csvreader))

print(f"total months: {int(lines)}")

#Net total amount of "Profit/Losses" over the entire period

total = sum(float(row[1]) for row in csvreader)

print (total)
```

Comment: I think `lines=len(list(csvreader))` probably reads through the entire file, leaving the file pointer at the end. So in `sum(float(row[1]) for row in csvreader)` there is no more data to read.

Comment: [Python csv.reader: How do I return to the top of the file?](//stackoverflow.com/q/431752)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks a lot!!!.. you link was the key to solve my questions. I was able to use ".seek(0)" to take the file pointer at the beginning again.